# Avoid dumping all TLB entries in QEMU

Tags: qemu, tlb

I tried to use `info tlb` in QEMU monitor to view the content of x86 TLB in QEMU. However, QEMU dumped all page mappings at one time and it overflowed my terminal. The guest OS's page table has already mapped tens of thousands of pages above `0xf0000000`.

I'd like to have a command like `info tlb 0xf0000000`, but QEMU complained:

```
tlb: extraneous characters at the end of line
```

How can I check only a few TLB entries in QEMU?